# I can't create a indepente org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I have a web Application Java class running into a Wildfly named Sincronizador. I did create a specific org.apache.log4j.Logger in Sincronizador.java but the `logger.log(...)` also put info in the Wildfly `server.log`. I would like to log info only in this logger

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SASComm.class);

logger.removeAllAppenders();

RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
rollingFileAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss SSS}][%p] %m%n"));
rollingFileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(7);
rollingFileAppender.setMaxFileSize("50MB");
rollingFileAppender.setName("Sinc");

rollingFileAppender.setFile(getLogFile());
rollingFileAppender.activateOptions();

logger.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `additivity` flag to `false` on your logger so that it doesn't inherit from a parent logger:

```
logger.setAdditivity(false);
```

This line `logger.removeAllAppenders();` will remove all the assigned appenders from this logger but the inheritance is still there (at least from the `rootLogger`) which you need to remove as well.